# Way to choose a parent if there are more than a certain amount of children?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with all parents and a table with all children.

Children rows take the parent rows' auto increment id number and they are related to their parents with that number. Every child has only 1 parent and parents can have about 200 children. So I want to select a parent when children count reaches to 200 (or children count>199) and list the parents with children counts.

Let's say on parent table: auto increment number column is called "ID", name is called "Name". On children table: parent id column is called "parentID", name is called cName

1: How do I select and list only the parents with their children count?

2: How do I select and list only the parents with children count>199?

Please explain your code when you post your answer so I can understand easily.

edit: here's what I tried and I don't know what I'm doing here:

```
$sql3 = 'SELECT parentTable.ID as ParentID,
                 b.TotalCount
      FROM parentTable a INNER JOIN
             (
            SELECT parentID, COUNT(1) as TotalCount
              FROM childTable
               WHERE tID = parentID
            GROUP BY threadID
             ) b 
         ON parentTable.ID = childTable.parentID
         AND childTable.TotalCount>199';
```

Comment: well I'm trying last 12 hours to figure it out but I couldn't figure it out. I'll add my last try but I didn't actually understand it.

Comment: @PrerakSola don't be so rude! go mind your own business if you won't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this below solution, it's not perfect but it works for now.

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(parentID) as total from parentTable INNER JOIN childTable ON parentTable.ID = childTable.parentID GROUP BY parentTable.ID
```

and for the second question here's the final, perfect query:

```
SELECT parentTable.ID, parentTable.Name, COUNT(parentID) as total from parentTable INNER JOIN childTable ON parentTable.ID = childTable.parentID GROUP BY parentTable.ID HAVING COUNT(parentID) > 199
```